# Iphone 5 apps wont fit Iphone 4

Tags: ios

So I've got bunch of buttons in my view and I've got AutoLayout checked. Most of buttons are custom with picture as their background. I watched bunch of videos on youtube about autolayout and constrains and it got confusing for me. When I add constrains to buttons they just become bigger and most of them aren't even visible on screen.

This is on Iphone 5, everything looks fine

[image]

This is on 3.5 inch screen Iphone 4

[image]

Anyone have some suggestions? I tried changing simalated metrics to 3.5 inch and when I run app on Iphone5 I've got 0.5 inches of free space

Comment: Ooh... tell tale sign there that you're using segues to navigate BACK from a view controller to its previous view controller. Is that the case? If so you are creating an infinite loop and your app will crash from memory pressure.

Comment: That's just while I am testing, later I will add Navigation bar and back button, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to diagnose the issue without seeing all the constraints. Of course, you have a lot of objects there and probably way too many constraints to make sense of here.

I would start by setting the constraints on your segmented control and the info button to hold a set distance from the bottom.

Then I would make a container view to hold all the other buttons within. The container view would be constrained to the superview and limited to a set distance from the top of the other controls.

Inside the container view, all the buttons constraints needed to space them equally. Then you will probably have to change them to autoresize, rather than intrinsic sizing for the image so that they can fill the available space and resize the image as appropriate.

If you want to keep all the buttons sized to suit the image, you'll need to use scrollview for the container and let the last row scroll down out of sight on the smaller screen.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try adding constrains your way